# Android Action Bar SHerlock i get error on setContentView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My project runs good on android 4 and above but i want to make id work on older versions so i turned to action bar sherlock. I implemented the library, i changed the theme, i extended SherlockActivity but when i try to run it on 2.3 i got the following error.

```
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:982)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:899)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:833)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:212)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at org.tracker.pms2.Home.onCreate(Home.java:42)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-10 20:08:33.403: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and when i double click to the 7th row it redirects me to this

```
  setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

anyone has any clue what is the problem?? :/

here is the manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true" 
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" >
                  </supports-screens>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/pecal_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

here is my values\styles:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_menu</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/background_menu</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you adding actiobarsherlock as library project?

Comment: You should check your /values/style

Comment: @wtsang02 i tried to change them but nothing happens :/

Comment: Are you using Theme.Sherlock as your parent style? Can you show that code so we can rule it out?

Comment: @gsingh2011 yes the Theme.Sherlock.Light i use as parent. I uploaded the styles and manifest. I also tried to use "@style/Theme.Sherlock" with the same results

Comment: Ok, I think the only way we're going to figure this out is if you post all of your code.

Comment: My Whole code is about 15 classes :/ For some reason something is wrong but i can't figure out what... When i try to run it on an android 4 emulator it passes the setContentView() but it gets stuck on an other point on the menu inflater

Answer (score 1):

It says `com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable` so your class name in Manifest probably is misspelled or isn't declared but somewhere in code you are trying to use it

Comment: No, it's not working. I don't know what i do wrong. Even when i try to run it on a android 4 emulator i still get an error

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know what's going on , i created a new application, i imported the Action Bar Sherlock library and i started copying an pasting the xmls and activities and so far it is working fine, if i step into a problem i will write again but creating a new application and FIRST importing the library seems to fix the problem